# How to use grep to find all files that contains two specific words?

Tags: linux, search, grep

I want to find all files that have both `patern1` and `patern2` words (not those that contain only one of them or none of them).

I used the following but it includes those that also have only one of the two words:

```
grep -r "patern1|patern2" /path/to/directory
```

Answer (score 1):

Variant 1:

```
find . -type f -exec grep -q pattern1 {} \; -a -exec grep -q pattern2 {} \; -a -print
```

Variant 2:

```
grep -rlZ pattern1 | xargs -r0 grep -l pattern2
```

You can combine this sequence for any number of patterns. `-Z` for `grep` and `-0` for `xargs` are required to handle names with spaces. If output must be null-terminated, add `-Z` to last `grep` too.

Answer (score 1):

Using `grep`

```
grep -re 'pattern1.*pattern2' -e 'pattern2.*pattern1' /path/to/directory
```

Answer (score 0):

I use the follow with

- ignoring lower uand upper case
- recursice in folder structure

`grep -rnwi . -e "searchstring" | grep -v "exclude string"`